# JS file is not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, jquery

JS for my main page is working..for example, I am using main_file.js for my default loaded page. Which is actually working properly.
but I have a search option on my default page which leads to some other .phtml file (named as second..phtml). js used for that .phtml is not working. even I have included it in the .xml file too.

This is how I declare js in .xml file for my default page .phtml

```
<script src="[CP_MODULE]::js/main_quickorder.js"/>
```

this how I declare js in .xml file of second .phtml.

```
<script src="[CP_MODULE]::js/test2.js"/>
```

first one is working properly but second one is not working.

Comment: It feels like a bit small amount of info, you should post how your components are declared and defined (xml, phtml, js)
Considering the amount info you gave it can be anything
a typo or you put your code in wrong xml file or you initialized the javascript in an invalid way

Comment: oky...I will try my level best to explain it again

Comment: Check in console that file is called or not

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to check than you thought.

1. First, you need to make sure that the JS file is in the page - Meaning your layout get updated, your definition is correct.

So you can search in the page for that file's name (view-source with ctrl-U or search in Element tab)

2. When we're sure the file is in the page, check the console, see if any red error happen? If so, then your JS `is running`, it just not running properly.
3. When 1 and 2 are done -> we know the file is in the page, there's no error. It's time to enter some code to signal that the JS file is working.

You can use `console.log` or `alert` to know that your file is working properly.

4. If none of those steps help, you may loading the file `improperly`.
   You need to provide more information about the xml, how you define layout, phtml and js files.

Answer (score -1):

You can also load the JS in the `phtml` template this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    '[CP_MODULE]::js/test2.js'
], function() {})
</script>
```

and make sure the `test2.js` file is in `app/code/CP/MODULE/view/frontend/web/js/test2.js`